# Unknown type ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, mvvm, mvvm-light, win-universal-app, viewmodellocator

I have seemed to hit a brick wall with this one.

I implemented the mvvm-light stuff as I have done previously while I am converting my Windows Phone app to a universal app.

I do however now get an issue in the App.xaml where it states that it cannot find the ViewModelLocator. I have as a result had a look at this blog post from Laurent for guidance without any luck. (http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2014/04/building-a-universal-application-for-windows-phone-8-1-and-windows-8-1-with-mvvm-light/)

I am using the latest version of mvvm-light (4.4.32.1).

If I comment out the line:
`<vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />`
it all builds and runs without an issue. As soon as I uncomment that line, I get the error:
Unknown type 'ViewModelLocator' in XML namespace 'typename desclaration'

I have also now suddenly got the following error:
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=619affe60327fc48' or one of its dependencies. The assembly version has a public key token that does not match that of the request.

In the project, I am referencing v 1.3 of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation as per the NuGet install...

Answer (score 0):

A while back I had that error, and it turned out that the real problem was in ViewModelLocator. I added a new Interface that had a problem (cannot remember if it was a static or public vs private issue). Anyway, commenting out the registration for it made the XAML compile again. Staring at the classes causing the problem eventually yielded the fix for them and thus ViewModelLocator.

I did not have the additional Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation error though.

Comment: I again played around with it without any success. I have created a project for a different app now doing exactly what I did for that app and don't experience the same issue. I will just recreate the app.